# Connection between iPhone-application and Java Server

Tags: java, ios, sockets

I want to establish a connection between the IOS Simulator and a Java Server. This is the IOS side:

```
 NSInputStream *in;
 NSOutputStream *out;

CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"192.168.0.11", 10025, &readStream, &writeStream);

in = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
out = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

[in setDelegate:self];
[out setDelegate:self];

[in scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[out scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[in open];
[out open];
```

And this is the Server side:

Constructor:

```
iphoneSocket = new ServerSocket(10025);
```

And in thread:

```
           DataOutputStream dOut;
           DataInputStream dIn;

          try {

            System.out.println("Lyssnar efter iphones");
            thirdSocket = iphoneSocket.accept();
            dOut = new DataOutputStream(thirdSocket.getOutputStream());
            dIn = new DataInputStream(thirdSocket.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("Connected from " + thirdSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(QuizWalkServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

The problem is that I can't connect. I dont receive the message in the console. What can be wrong?

HAnk

Comment: You did not posit a question.

Comment: Try with [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] instead of [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]

Comment: Thanks, but it didnt work.

Comment: Hum, that  exactly what I did. It works just well.

Comment: Ok, something else must be wrong in my file then.